# How to stop all Hangfire jobs

Tags: c#, hangfire

Is there a way to stop all available and running Hangfire jobs and start them after completing my custom method?

In this scenario I need to run a method, but before that I should stop and terminate all running Hangfire jobs and after completing my method I should restart them all.

I simply add Hangfire to my asp.net core project like its [documentation](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/quick-start.html)

Comment: Are you referring to a long running job or jobs that have been queued?

Comment: Queued one, I want to stop all queued jobs and start them after my method finished.

Answer (score 0):

From the sounds of it, you are wanting to do something that used to be available in hangfire but was depreciated in 2015 (and has since been heavily requested to be re-added)

if you jump over to [This Issue On GitHub](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/issues/225) it has several peoples workarounds to essentially pause / stop jobs and then resume them later.

Comment: Yeah, I've looked through all of them, but none of them was handy in fact.